# Ошибка миграции в проекте WinForms .NET 4.6

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, миграция

Не могу найти связь, с какого момента стал получать описанную ниже ошибку. Использую 17 студию, начал получать ошибку миграции :

> Your startup project doesn't reference
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the
>   Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is
>   correct, install the package, and try again.

Понимаю, что полный бред, так как в проекте EF6, не Core, но все равно попробовал импортировать указанную библиотеку, на что получил предсказуемую ошибку.
С чем может быть связана ошибка?

[image: скрин]

Comment: У вас скачанный пакет требует кору. Поклацайте свои пакеты в менеджере (там снизу вы увидите  зависимости)...вот там где увидите `core` - ищите альтернативу. Обычно если пакети юзает кору, это пишется в названии (или в описании)

Comment: Можете приложить в вопрос (фото, или текст, или и то и другое) свои пакеты

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц спасибо дополнил. Не было в проекте ничего связанного с Core.

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` не имеет отношения к .NET Core. Это библиотека ядра  самого EF ([см. перевод](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/core)). Обновите или переустановите библиотеки EF под NET 4.6.